# jQuery cropper/area selector with zoom/pan function

Tags: jquery, image, select, crop, area

I'm searching for a jQuery plugin for some image area selection. I need to extract x, y for a rectangle and save the coordinates in my database.

I have a working case already, so this is just a question if a plugin which supports both crop/area selection and zooming/panning.

I've been through all the plugins on this page http://techslides.com/image-zoom-drag-and-crop-with-html5 and none of the plugins support both.

It's an image of about 1000x1000 so it would be perfect if I could zoom in and then make the selection, zoom out while still having the aspect ratio of the image/zoom setting.

I hope you can help me in the right direction. If it doesn't exist, I'm going to develop and make it public for others to use :-)

Best regards
Jens